# Reading mutliple tables from single Arrow file

Tags: pyarrow, apache-arrow

I have created an Arrow IPC file containing multiple tables. How can I read the tables one by one using `pyarrow`? Is there an example?

Following the documentation from [Tabular Datasets](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/dataset.html) I am able to read only the last table written in the file.

The file is produced with C++, by multiple calls to:

```
// table is a std::shared_ptr<arrow::Table> containing each
// time a table, multiple different schemas are used. filePath
// is an std::string with the destination file path.
// myFile is an std::shared_ptr<arrow::io::FileOutputStream>
// created with
// arrow::io::FileOutputStream::Open(params.outputPath,true)
//    .ValueOrDie()
void arrowTableWrite() {
    ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(auto writer, arrow::ipc::MakeFileWriter(myFile->get(), table->schema()));
    writer->WriteTable(*table);
    writer->Close();
}
```

Trying to read the created file with python:

```
import pyarrow as pa
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with pa.OSFile(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as source:
        table = pa.ipc.open_file(source).read_all()
        print(table)
```

The above prints:

```
pyarrow.Table
id: int32 not null
value: binary not null
```

I would expect to see all the tables contained in the file, I have verified that the data is written.

Comment: Could you give some code examples for how you are writing and reading data and actual vs expected output?

Comment: @MicahKornfield Thanks for the comment, I have added additional information to the question. Please let me know if you would like to see something additional.

Comment: So one issue is each time a call to  arrowTableWrite is made it will overwrite the previous file.   A possible second issue based on the description might be that you expect to be able to write data with different schemas to the file, this isn't supported.  All data must have the same schema (and you won't be able to really divide tables back up again easily, unless each table has only one RecordBatch in it).

Comment: @MicahKornfield Thanks, that answers my question. I wanted to write tables with different schemas on the same file, that is not supported.

Comment: If you knew all schemas ahead of time you could use a union of struts to emulate this behavior

Comment: @MicahKornfield I have edited the body of `arrowTableWrite`, `myFile` my file is a shared pointer among each `arrowTableWrite` invocation, so I think the issue was not on each call overwriting the output file.

Comment: Each file has a footer which references back to it's blocks.  One of two things could be happening.  Each time the writer is open it is appending an entirely new contents or it is truncating the file before doing any writes.  Without looking at the code is guess the first.   Constant appends effectively make the preceding file contents invisible to readers (or maybe just corrupting the file altogether)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the discussion in the comments with Micah Kornfield, it was clarified that the IPC *file* format does not support writing multiple tables in the same file.

To support this functionality, one can use the IPC *stream* format. Specifically, instead of creating a file writer with `MakeFileWriter`, a file created with `MakeStreamWriter` can support multiple tables, with possibly different schemas, written in the same IPC file.

[MakeStreamWriter documentantion](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/api/ipc.html?highlight=make%20streamwriter#_CPPv416MakeStreamWriterPN2io12OutputStreamERKNSt10shared_ptrI6SchemaEERK15IpcWriteOptions)